# Can't Connect to PPTP VPN When Using NETGEAR N300 Router

Tags: linux, ubuntu, router, vpn

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm able to connect to the VPN on other networks, just not the one in my house.  I'm pretty sure that my router is blocking the connection.  How can I fix this?

Output from my Syslog:

```
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 3065
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> VPN connection 'PI' (Connect) reply received.
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 pppd[3069]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 pppd[3069]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 pppd[3069]: Using interface ppp0
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 pppd[3069]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/0
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3073]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
May  3 16:44:00 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
May  3 16:44:01 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
May  3 16:44:01 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
May  3 16:44:01 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 3155).
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:258]: Closing connection (shutdown)
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 pptp[3085]: nm-pptp-service-3065 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 pppd[3069]: Modem hangup
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 pppd[3069]: Connection terminated.
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 pppd[3069]: Exit.
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> Policy set 'c:/virus.exe' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
May  3 16:44:12 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

Comment: What is this?
`May  3 16:44:07 jaredSatelliteL650 NetworkManager[788]: <info> Policy set 'c:/virus.exe' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.`

Comment: The girlfriend decided to name our wifi network 'c:/virus.exe' (-_-)

Comment: That's pretty funny, if rather mean!

Answer (score 1):

```
/sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
```

Have a look at [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/418214), because you're getting the same. As mentioned there, check if you're using `libgcrypt11=1.5.0-3ubuntu2.2`, because there is [a confirmed bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgcrypt11/+bug/1217183) affecting that version that is not present in *ubuntu2.1.

Also have a look at [this mini configuration guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/295309), and check that you have the correct authentication methods and MPPE enabled.